# Angular JS how to trigger update on ngModel change

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have two fields of type date used for dates, and have their value watched by this piece of code:
HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="end" id="end" ng-model="orderlist.end" />
```

JS using Controller As:

```
$rootScope.$watch(
function(){ return self.start},
function(){ self.orders.get()}
)
$rootScope.$watch(
function(){ return self.end},
function(){ self.orders.get(),true}
)
```

all works fine so far, then I have implemented a datepicker made with JQuery [Datepicker code is here](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#min-view-mode)

Update : the change is not reflected when i pick a date
the function self.orders.get() does not get called.
I've heard it has something to do with a code outside Angular so that angular is not aware of the change.
What is the correct way to do it? thank you.

Comment: What does `orders.get()` do?

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ . It does alot of work for you ;)

Comment: orders.get() is an ajax call like : $http.get('url').then(function(response){ //...}

Comment: @jvecsei okay since it's a pure angular solution i will have a try and it has a lot of useful directives too

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to use watchers because watchers are expensive. you can use ng-change directive, and whenever value changes, call self.order.get(),

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="end" id="end" ng-change="getOrder()" ng-model="orderlist.end"  />
```

And in controller

```
$scope.getOrder = function (){
     self.orders.get(); // or whatever is your logic.
}
```

Comment: Doesn't make sense to use $scope here, since OP's has controller as.

Comment: I did not gave him a complete working code.. I just tried to help him by giving an idea how he can do..

Comment: thank you for the ng-change directive which works, however I previously the ngModel reflected the change is wrong, it just stays the same even when i change the value by clicking the datepicker icon....

Comment: thank you... happy to hear that... there is no other answer yet, can you mark     it selected/best answer...